# Jmeter: lots of Connection: close in response header

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to do load testing against index page(static page) of my websit.
There are lots of errors in the test reulst because of connection closed.
Any tips why server(apache 2.2) decide to close the connection?

=============http headers===============
Load time:1055
Connect Time: 845
Latency: 1055
Size in bytes:98
Body size in bytes: 0

GET https://mysite/index.html
GET data:
[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Host: mysite
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)

Response headers:
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://mysite/splash.html
**Connection: close**

Answer (score 0):

Check your Mysql database connection pool size, During the load test you create number of thread it may insufficient to your mysql connection configuration.

you can increase max_connections in my.cnf

Comment: the page tested is a static web page . I will add the information to the question describtion.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following JMeter configuration amendment:

1. Change "Implementation" of all your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to `HttpClient4`. The fastest and the easiest way of doing this for all the samplers is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults)
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
3. In the *hc.parameters* file add the next line:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```
4. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up

More information: [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)

Comment: I am using httpclient4, this does not work for my env. Changing to httpclient3 also not resolve the problem.